# Re-send processed message to Amazon SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I got a message in my queue which is processed successfully and now deleted from the queue.

Is it possible to resend the same message to the same queue?

Comment: If you need to keep the message in the queue after processing then would you delete it?

Comment: I don't want to keep the message in the queue. But if I need to reprocess/modify the previous message's result then I want to resend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in capability to "re-send" messages.

You would need to write some code that sends a message to the queue.